# How can I properly calculate the isoelectric point (pI) of amino acids?

Tags: acid-base, biochemistry, amino-acids

The following amino acid is called *[lysine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysine)*. I was asked to calculate its isoelectric point, with the given $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ values.

[image: lysine-structure-with-pka-values]

I've searched a lot, and the most helpful post that I found was [How do I calculate the isoelectric point of amino acids with more than two pKa's?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/55685/63955)
According to orthocresol's answer:

> Since the $\mathrm{pI}$ is the $\mathrm{pH}$ at which the amino acid has no overall net charge, you need to average the $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ values relevant to the protonation/deprotonation of the form **with no net charge**.

Let's call the ends $e_1, e_2$ and $e_3$ (from left to right).

## Approach $\#1$

- deprotonate $e_3$ (i.e., carboxyl group)
- deprotonate $e_1$ or $e_2$ [neutral point]

So, $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$'s of $e_1$ and $e_2$ are **relevant**.

$$\Rightarrow \mathrm{pI} = \frac{10.53 + 8.95}{2} = 9.74$$

But, is there some limit to number of protonations/deprotonations or some procedures to follow?

For instance,

## Approach $\#2$

- deprotonate $e_1$
- deprotonate $e_3$ [neutral point]
- deprotonate $e_2$ and protonate $e_1$ [neutral point]

This time, $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$'s of $e_3$ and $e_1$ are relevant. But, the calculated $\mathrm{pI}$ isn't correct.

So, how can I validate the approaches?

---

Problem source: FIITJEE study material

$\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ and $\mathrm{pI}$ values table for amino acids: https://www.anaspec.com/html/pK_n_pl_Values_of_AminoAcids.html

Comment: The first approach I'd say is the correct one. It's obvious that the isoelectric point will be between e1 and e2 because lysine is a dibasic aminoacid, therefore the two amino groups will have a bigger influence on the pI than the acidic group, thus rendering the pI basic. In these cases, as far as I know, you have to find the average of 2 pKa-values that are going to have the biggest influence on the pI. In this case, since there are 3 pKa-values of which 2 are basic, the pI will be the arithmetic mean of those values.

Comment: Related: Various pI calculators for proteins give different results: [ExPASy](https://web.expasy.org/compute_pi/) (8.75), [isoelectric.org](http://isoelectric.org/) (9.04), and [Prot pi](https://www.protpi.ch/Calculator/ProteinTool/) (8.475).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Isoelectric point of an amino acid is the $\mathrm{pH}$ at which the molecule carries no net charge<sup>[1]</sup>. It can be calculated by the average of the relevant $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ values as you have mentioned.

Your confusion seems to stem from choosing the relevant $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ values. For this we should refer to the titration curve of the amino acid.

**For a neutral amino acid**<sup>[2]</sup>:

[image: titration curve 1]

From the curve we can infer that the $\mathrm{pI}$ is simply the average of the two $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ values of the carboxylic acid and the amino group.

**For a basic amino acid**<sup>[2]</sup>:

[image: titration curve 2]

From the curve we can infer that the $\mathrm{pI}$ is simply the average of the two $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ values of the two amino groups. The $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ of the carboxylic acid group is not relevant.

**For an acidic amino acid**<sup>[3]</sup>:

[image]

From the curve we can infer that the $\mathrm{pI}$ is simply the average of the two $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ values of the two carboxylic acid groups. The $\mathrm pK_\mathrm a$ of the amino group is not relevant.

**Here are examples for all three cases:**

[image]

**References:**

1. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isoelectric_point)
2. [Titration curves for neutral and basic amino acids](https://aminodotnet.weebly.com/isoelectric-points.html)
3. [Titration curve for acidic amino acids](http://faculty.une.edu/com/courses/bionut/distbio/obj-512/Chap6-titration-aspartate.html)

Comment: But [ExPASy](https://web.expasy.org/compute_pi/) says that pI is 8.75 for lysine (K).

Comment: @PeterMortensen please refer https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Essential_Organic_Chemistry_(Bruice)/16%3A_The_Organic_Chemistry_of_Amino_Acids%2C_Peptides%2C_and_Proteins/16.04%3A_The_Isoelectric_Point and https://www.anaspec.com/html/pK_n_pl_Values_of_AminoAcids.html